# Find the probability that equation has two solutions of different signs

Tags: probability, inequality

I have 3 random variables $\xi_1, \xi_2,\xi_3$ which are independent and uniformly distributed on segments $[-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}], [-\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{3}], [-\sqrt{\pi }, \sqrt{\pi}]$ respectively.

I need to find the probability, that equation

[image] $=0$

has two solutions of **different signs** with respect to parameter $t$.

After some calculations I found out that variables must satisfy the following inequality:

$\xi_1^2 + \frac{\xi_2^2}{2} + \frac{\xi_3^2}{3} \gt 1 $

How can I find all the values ​​of variables $\xi_1, \xi_2,\xi_3$ that satisfy this inequality?

**EDIT:**

With Calvin Lin hint I've got:

$|\xi_1|\gt 1 $

$|\xi_2|\gt \sqrt{2} $

$|\xi_3|\gt \sqrt{3} $

So the probability that equation has two solutions of different signs will be:

$ P = 1 - \frac{\frac{4}{3}\pi\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}}{8\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}\sqrt{\pi}}  \approx 0.7$

I'm not sure in my reasoning. Can anyone fix my conclusions, if they are wrong. I am a little embarrassed that I obtain an infinite decimal ..

Comment: Your equation doesn't have an equals sign...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Consider the volume of the solid ellipsoid given by

$$ x^2 + \frac { y^2} {2} + \frac { z^2} {3} \leq 1. $$

Comment: Thank you! I've edit my question. Did I understand your hint correctly?

Comment: @AnnOrlova No you did not. The idea is to use geometric probability. The total region is given by $[-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}] \times [-\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{3}] \times [-\sqrt{\pi}, \sqrt{\pi} ] $, which has volume $A$ (to be determined). The region which doesn't work, is the solid ellipsoid, which has volume $B$. [Note that the solid ellipsoid is contained within the probability space.] Hence, the probability of success is $1 - \frac {B}{A}$